# How to pass array data to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

**Controller**

```
public function Payment()
    {
        $PayData= array('MainCategory'=>$MainCategory , 'Price'=>$Price , 'AddId'=>$AddId );
        return view('classifieds.Pay')->with('store', $PayData);
    }
```

pay.blade.php

```
{{$PayhereData->MainCategory}}
```

this code is not working , how to pass manualy created aray data to view

Answer (score 1):

**As it is you can pass that array to `with()` function**

like this

```php
public function Payment()
{
    $PayData = array('MainCategory' => $MainCategory, 'Price' => $Price, 'AddId' => $AddId);
    return view('classifieds.Pay')->with($PayData);
}
```

then in

### **pay.blade.php**

you can call `{{ $MainCategory }}` and `{{ $Price }}` and `{{ $AddId }}`

Answer (score 1):

**write code in Your method like**

```
public function Payment()
{
    $PayData = array('MainCategory' => $MainCategory, 'Price' => $Price, 'AddId' => $AddId);
    return view('classifieds.Pay', $PayData );
}
```

**your pay.blade.php**

```
MainCategory  : {{ $MainCategory }} 
Price         : {{ $Price }} 
AddId         : {{ $AddId }}
```

Comment: have you tested your code before answering?? this will make an error if you try to use `{{ $MainCategory }}` directly in blade as the variable is inside an array.

Comment: now you have updated your answer :D you should test your code before answering.

Answer (score 1):

**Example Data**

```
  $MainCategory = 'cat';
  $Price = 20;
  $AddId = 1;
```

**simply you can use `get_defined_vars()` to pass all variables ...**

```
  return view('classifieds.Pay',get_defined_vars());
```

**also you can pass as `array`...**

```
return view('classifieds.Pay',[
    'MainCategory' =>$MainCategory,
    'Price' =>$Price,
    'AddId' =>$AddId,
]);
```